# How to get all instances of the same process in perfmon

Tags: xml, windows, perfmon

In perfmon (performance monitor), same instances of a process are denoted by

```
processabc
processabc#1
processabc#2
```

Is there any way to call ALL instances of the same process in xml (template), without knowing how many instances there are?

Here's my xml template so far:

```
<Counter>\Process(Processabc)\% Processor Time</Counter>
<Counter>\Process(Processabc#1)\% Processor Time</Counter>
```

I want to select n instances or all instances of processabc in a single line.

I know that to select all processes on a computer, it's possible to use

```
<Counter>\Process(*)\% Processor Time</Counter>
```

I was wondering if I could do something similar to solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Wild-Cards

Yes, you can select all instances of a specific process.

The asterix `*` is a wild-card character that specifies **any sequence of characters of an unspecified length, including no length at all**.

So the counter you mentioned `<Counter>\Process(*)\% Processor Time</Counter>` simply selects *any process whose name has zero or more characters*.

## Wild-Cards Applied

To apply this to your circumstance, simply prefix the wild-card with the process name. I performed a test using Chrome, the counter was specified as follows:

```
<Counter>\Process(chrome*)\% Processor Time</Counter>
```

This means:

> select any process with the name *chrome* followed by zero or more
> characters.

The resultant report is shown below.

Note: If you log to a text-based format (comma/tab-separated values), perfmon will not select instances created after you started the collection. You should log to binary format, and later use `relog.exe` to convert back to csv if needed. Details in [Windows performance monitor new instances](https://serverfault.com/a/140318/158755)

[image]

Comment: This worked in 2021, thank you. But to add wildcard symbol I had to save my counter selection as a template which is actually an XML file, edited it manually and re-created the data collector set.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issue, however in my case it wasn't working even when I have wildcard selected. In the report I saw only Total Instance.

However I find out when you go to the report and you select with right mouse the context menu and select:
"Private Bytes counter - Properties - Data - Add - Process - Private Bytes"
here you can Select All instances. Press OK and you should be able to see all instances now.